# How can I update an assignment in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, observer-pattern

I want to know how I can do the following:

```
var x = Observed<String>("hello")
label.text = x
```

Somewhere else `x` is updated:

```
x.value = "World"
```

Then `label.text` is automatically updated. Here is what I have for `Observed` so far

```
class Observed<T> {
    typealias Observer = (T)->()

    var observer: Observer?

    var value: T {
        didSet {
            if let observer = observer {
                observer(value)
            }
        }
    }

    init(_ v: T) {
        value = v
    }
}
```

I believe this is sort of what RxSwift, etc. do, but that's overkill for what I'm doing

Comment: Look at Property Observers in [Apple's Language Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) didSet will be called when the property chnages

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use a `didSet` in this scenario.

```
class YourClass {
   var x: String = "" { didSet {  someVC.someLabel.text = x } }
}
```

There is no "native" data binding in iOS as of now.

EDIT: of course there is KVO, thanks @matt for the heads-up :)

Comment: That's not really true. There's always been key-value observing, which is all data binding is. And of course in iOS 13 (though you could not have known this when you wrote this answer), Combine effectively makes RxSwift native.